# Creating a function or classes aliases without uses eval

Tags: php, eval, alias

I want know if, on PHP, is possible to create a function (or class) aliases without uses eval() and only with native methods. Eval don't is recomended for some developers and I'm building a framework -- I prefer don't uses eval too.

Currently, I do something like:

```
    eval('function aliases_x(){ return x(); }');
```

It's all!

Bye.

**Edit**: sorry for miss that... I need do it at an automatic method.

Example:

```
function create_aliases($real_method, $new_name) { ... }

create_aliases('x', 'aliasses_x');
```

Comment: Why not just create the function normally, without using eval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to alias a class, you can use [`class_alias`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php). To alias a function you are a little more limited. Most suggestions I've seen suggested the use of create_function or the new anonymous function syntax

```
$aliases_x = function($v) { return x($v); };
// OR
$aliases_x = create_function('$v', 'return x($v);');
```

Comment: Good one about `class_alias`. About functions both methods don't solve my problem :(. But I don't need anymore of that function aliasses. I will accept you answer. Thanks :)